# Pattern matching against List variable

Tags: f#

Why does the second pattern matching return "1 and 2" and give me a warning "This rule will never be matched" on the wildcard _?

```
let a = [3;4]

match a with
    |[1;2] -> "1 and 2"
    |_ -> "Other"
|> printfn "%A"

let lst = [1;2]
match a with
    |lst -> "1 and 2"
    |_ -> "Other"
|> printfn "%A"
```

It appears to me lst is considered truthy. How so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An identifier in lowercase matches with everything and binds the identifier to the value.

If you want to compare `lst` with `a` you need to use `when` which is a conditional guard:

```
let a = [3;4]

match a with
    |[1;2] -> "1 and 2"
    |_ -> "Other"
|> printfn "%A"

let lst = [1;2]
match a with
    | b when b = lst -> "1 and 2"
    |_ -> "Other"
|> printfn "%A"
```

but in this case a simple `if then else` would work.

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd pattern matching you have two different `lst` variables with the same name. Here,

```
let lst = [1;2]
match a with
    | lst -> "1 and 2"
    | _ -> "Other"
```

in the 1st match case you don't refer to the `lst` variable above, you create a new one. You can check it by trying to refactor-rename it (F2 in Visual Studio). As AMieres explains, case is important.

In general, referring to a variable in a match case is doable yet not trivial.
Consider this code:

```
let helloWorld = "hello world"

let isHelloWorld s =
    match s with
    | helloWorld -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Here you will get the same warning as described. One way to go is to mark the constant with the `[<Literal>]` attribute and to make it upper-case at the same time:

```
[<Literal>]
let HelloWorld = "hello world"

let isHelloWorld s =
    match s with
    | HelloWorld -> true
    | _ -> false
```

This would work as expected. However, you can apply the `[<Literal>]` attribute only to [certain types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals), and list is not among them. For those, you have to leverage `when` conditions in match cases.